# Preview tab is empty for the request sent in Postman tool

Tags: api-testing, postman

Am new to POSTMAN tool and when I send a request am getting the response status as '200 ok'.
But in Preview tab, the page is not displaying and its empty. How to view the response in preview tab?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your raw response? Probably there is nothing to display

Comment: Alexey, I have added the Raw response in above.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither the native nor the Chrome Postman app are particularly great with HTML previews, especially with dynamic content, such as the search results you have on your screenshot.

If you check the Raw tab, you'll see the actual HTML code returned, and if you just want to look at the page, you might as well use your browser.

The point of Postman is mostly that you can *process* the response, either to assert some of the values, or to use them in a subsequent API call.

If you're just getting started with Postman and trying to figure out how it works, you cold use a free public API for practicing. Something that returns JSON. You can find good free ones on ProgrammableWeb.

Or if you actually want to process google search results, then use the API: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview